# Sketch the pre-image $f^{-1}(A)$ where $f(x,y) =\cos(x+y)$ on $A = [1,2]$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality, elementary-set-theory

**Question:** Explaining your working, sketch the pre-image $f^{-1}(A)$ where $f(x,y) = \cos(x+y)$ on $A = [1,2].$

**So far I have:**

\begin{align}
& f^{-1}([1,2]) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid f(x,y) \in [1,2] \} \\[6pt]
= {} & \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid f(x,y) \in [1,2] \} \\[6pt]
= {} & \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 1 \leq \cos(x+y) \leq 2 \}
\end{align}

I am not sure where to go from here or how to sketch this graph.

How do I sketch this pre-image?

Comment: An observation that may help: of all the points in $[1, 2]$, only $1$ is in the range of the cosine, so $f^{-1}([1, 2])$ really is  $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I missed that, I was making the question more difficult in my head than it actually is.

Comment: Our cognitive machinery can really mess with our understanding of an exact-science problem--indeed, one key way our mathematical education adds value is by alerting us to our tacit or intuitive assumptions.  As Harald Bohr is credited with saying, "If mathematics doesn't teach us to think correctly, it at least teaches us how easy it is to think incorrectly.":)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x$ and $y$ are real, the cosine cannot be in $[1,2]$ except by being equal to $1.$ And the cosine is equal to $1$ only when its argument is a multiple of $2\pi.$ So the preimage is
$$
\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : \text{for some } n\in\mathbb Z,\,\,\, x+y = 2\pi n \}.
$$
The graph of $x+y= 2\pi n$ for any particular $n$ is a straight line with slope $-1.$

So the preimage is the union of infinitely many parallel lines.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I would start by noticing that $f(x,y) = \cos(x+y)\in[-1,1]$. Thus we have that
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(A) & = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid f(x,y)\in [1,2]\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid f(x,y)\in \{1\}\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid f(x,y)\in (1,2]\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid \cos(x+y) = 1\}\cup\varnothing\\\\
& = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid (x+y = 2k\pi)\wedge(k\in\mathbb{Z})\}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?